# How can i get the files saved inside the iPhone into UITableView in app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am totally blank on how to get the files stored in iPhone (photos, videos, pdf, ppt and so on) and on how to make a list of them in a `UITableView` of the iPhone App. Here, I want to list out the files stored in iPhone Device. If anyone has a solution for this, help me. I googled and could not find any solutions.

Comment: In iOS there is no file system like on a normal pc. All files are stored within the applications sandbox. Meaning that you can't access files that belong to an other app. Only files sorted within the document directory of your app can be accessed from your app.

Comment: To list out the photos you have the PhotoLibrary which you can access using imagePicker, similarly for the music and stuff you need to import a framework in your project and add the required methods. For that google each requirement separately like how to import photos from photolibrary etc....

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i have sorted out the images by using UIImagePickerController, now i am doubt of how to get the audio files and other documents(doc, ppt) and all.

Comment: Try looking at the answer to my question here, it explains how to display an NSArray of files in the Documents folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288912/displaying-nsarray-of-files-in-a-uitableview-ios-5

Comment: @jireh this link for Only getting audio library to UITableView 

http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-custom-ios-music-player/